# Can a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) have their hard drives upgraded

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, hardware-recommendation

My friend has a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) -- she wants to install a magnetic 2.5" HDD. Can I install any such drive or do they have to be apple compatible hardware.

Comment: Depends, is it the Retina MacBook Pro or is it the non-Retina MacBook Pro that hasn't been updated since mid-2012?

Comment: Opps @user24601I had the wrong make and model -- it's a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) -- updated the question

Comment: In that case, orkoden is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. There's not enough room for a spinning hard drive to be connected inside any retina portable MacBook.

That being said - hose drive would work well externally via thunderbolt or USB and internal non-OEM replacements are available.

To [install special SSDs](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/266806/Install+bigger+SSD+possible+with+latest+model). other than Apple branded look for resellers and online like OWC or RamJet.

Comment: Opps @user24601I had the wrong make and model -- it's a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) -- updated the question

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same, see the link.